# Uploadify does not upload

Tags: javascript, php, uploadify

I have a slight problem with Uploadify :)
It does not upload files (probably is an issue with upload folder settings)... I read all discussions here, tested quite varians but still no success.
So - here is my index.php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php $timestamp = time();?>
    $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'formData'     : {
                'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
            },
            'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
            'auto'     : false,
            'fileSizeLimit' : '50MB',
            'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png; *.jpeg; *.tif; *.pdf',
            'uploadLimit' : 2,
            'removeCompleted' : false

        });
    });
</script>
```

I have a folder named "uploads" inside the uploadify folder where I wand to store the uploaded files. The uploadify.php looks like this:

```
<?php
var_dump($_FILES);
var_dump($_POST);

$targetFolder = '/uploads';

$verifyToken = md5('unique_salt' . $_POST['timestamp']);

if (!empty($_FILES) && $_POST['token'] == $verifyToken) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
var_dump(is_writable($targetPath));
$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];


$fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); 
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo '1';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid file type.';
}
}
?>
```

the uploads' folder permissions are 755.
The check-exist.php file is:

```
<?php

$targetFolder = '/uploads'; 
if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder . '/' . $_POST['filename'])) {
echo 1;
} else {
echo 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "[it] does not upload files"?  Do you see any errors?  Does it not send the file to the server?  Is the file not copied into the right folder?  Have you tried any debugging on your own?

Comment: No errors - the script shows that files are uploaded, but the uploads folder is empty. The demo page is on: http://k-prim.biz/ljubo/up3/

Comment: What do you see if you do `var_dump(is_writable($targetPath));`?  How about `var_dump($_FILES)`?  Are you sure the `$_POST['token']` is matching?  There are a handful of things here that could be wrong.

Comment: How can I add your code to the code above? Sorry for my question but my php knowledge is quite close to 0 :)

Comment: `var_dump` is a function that echos out the value of the variable/expression.  So put `var_dump($_FILES);` and `var_dump($_POST);` at the top, and `var_dump(is_writable($targetPath));` after you declare `$targetPath`.

Comment: I added those in uploadify.php - see the code above but still no messages or uploads

Comment: You're gonna need to open your dev tools and look at the network traffic to see what the PHP is printing.\

Comment: ... and where do I have to look here... (http://k-prim.biz/ljubo/up3/screen.png)

Comment: Did you have that open while the file was uploading?  You want to look at `uploadify.php`.  I'm seeing: `move_uploaded_file(/home/bgvetcom/public_html/k-prim.biz/uploads/file.png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/bgvetcom/public_html/k-prim.biz/ljubo/up3/uploadify.php on line 26`